# kafka stream taskId meaning

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

can someone explain how to read a kafka stream  taskId i.e. 2_0 or 0_0. I understand that the second digit is a partition, but what is the first digit, and how to read it from a kafka stream application stand point.

So far in my understanding, a task is a partition based instantiation of a sub-topology ( i.e. atomic topology).

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-kafka-streams/content/kafka-streams-TaskId.html

Comment: Red that but what is topic group id

Comment: Ah i think i get it, it is the sub-topology number, and then the partition. But that topic group id name makes no sense to me. group id maybe, as in each sub-topology is like a kafka application i.e. u  have a group id for it. so what's the topic stand for in topic group id, is what i don't get